# Gradle android.application

Tags: http, gradle

need help with this

Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.sal.f.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-vision:v1-rev16-1.22.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0' exclude module: 'httpclient'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.20.0' exclude module: 'httpclient'


}
```

Comment: Read the error and then look at the last 2 lines of the dependencies section...

Comment: And maybe state what your problem is.

Comment: Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.1.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.

Comment: i just removed the last 2 lines